# Как вернуть результат одной функции в другую?

Tags: python

```
CARS = ['Audi', 'BMW', 'Lada', 'Ferrari', 'Ford']

def show_count_cars(count_cars):
    text = 'У тебя ' + str(count_cars) + ' машин'
    return text

def process_query(query):
    if query == 'Сколько у меня машин?':
        count = len(CARS)
        show_count_cars(count)

print(process_query('Сколько у меня машин?'))
```

Comment: собственно вы уже использовали оператор `return`. Похоже, в вашем случае необходимо `show_count_cars(count)` заменить на `return show_count_cars(count)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже было сказано [@Viktorov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/179846/viktorov), добавьте `return` перед вызовом `show_count_cars(count)` в функции `process_query(query)`. В результате код должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
CARS = ['Audi', 'BMW', 'Lada', 'Ferrari', 'Ford']

def show_count_cars(count_cars):
    text = 'У тебя ' + str(count_cars) + ' машин'
    return text

def process_query(query):
    if query == 'Сколько у меня машин?':
        count = len(CARS)
        return show_count_cars(count)

print(process_query('Сколько у меня машин?'))
```